First and last frames doesn't match in loop
I've been creating this scene with two exact copies of the same object, to create loop effect, but, somehow I have my first frame brighter than last one. Textures are identical, gradient is horizontal 90degrees, no additional lightning:

I can't figure out what does that.
Here is link for first and last frame, and project file
Images and project
Blender File: 

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

you have two "loops" geometry over each other.

Just make your "original instance" invisible (uncheck checkbox in the outliner) and it works.

wow, what a shame to make this mistake)))) thank you very much)

not really - you won't believe what i do wrong...and not just once...
